# Java: Creating multiple (duplicate) buttons that perform the same action but to themselves

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

BACKGROUND INFO: I want to make a 9x9 grid of buttons that act as empty beds. All buttons say "Add bed" and when clicked open up a window to write data about the occupant. Once saved the button will change to an occupied bed image.

QUESTION: Is it possible to create an event listener that does the same thing for each button, but applies it to the button being pressed? Im new to java but I understand that good code should be able to do this in a few lines rather than 100+

CODE:

```
    //button1 (inside the gui function)
    addBed1 = new JButton("Add bed"); //button 1 of 9
    addBed1.addActionListener(new room1Listener());

class room1Listener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        addBed1.setText("Adding bed..);
        addBedGui(); //Generic window for adding bed info.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an event listener that does the same thing for each button, but applies it to the button being pressed? Im new to java but I understand that good code should be able to do this in a few lines rather than 100+

Absolutely. In fact you can create one ActionListener object and add this same listener to each and every button in a for loop. The ActionListener will be able to get a reference to the button that pressed it via the `ActionEvent#getSource()` method, or you can get the JButton's actionCommand String (usually its text) via the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand()` method.

e.g.,

```
// RoomListener, not roomListener
class RoomListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) event.getSource();
        btn.setText("Adding bed..);
        addBedGui(); //Generic window for adding bed info.
    }
}
```

and

```
RoomListener roomListener = new RoomListener();
JButton[] addButtons = new JButton[ADD_BUTTON_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < addButtons.length; i++) {
   addButtons[i] = new JButton("     Add Bed     "); // make text big
   addButtons[i].addActionListener(roomListener);
   addBedPanel.add(addButtons[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, this works perfect thanks! And for anyone else reading, to find a unique ID, inside the roomListener, add 'int id = event.getSource().hashCode()'.. Im assuming from there we can use a switch case to give the right logic to act based on the button pressed.